# Why is print different from Corel X5 than from PDF - Same file

Tags: adobe-acrobat, corel-draw

I have Corel Draw X5 and I have some files which print differently from Corel and the PDF which was created by the same Corel program.

I am not worried about the screen look but they do all look the same, even the PDF, but when printed on a Xerox Phaser 6250 it is washed out compared to the print from Corel.

I have checked the printer setting, PDF and Corel settings and I cannot see what would cause this.

Corel X5 and Acrobat 8 - Phaser 6250 Laser - glossy and plain paper - RGB and CMYK settings.

Any help please?

oz

Comment: There might be useful information here even though the question is different https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/104186/why-does-osx-print-a-bolder-image-than-windows-in-illustrator

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem in my previous workplace. I still have no idea what is causing this but we converted everything to a bitmap with 300dpi in Corel, then save the PDF and then reverse the changes in Corel, so you have editability.
We used Minolta bizhub 220 and Corel 12, so I can only guess it has something to do with the PDF. 
If that helps in any way.

Answer (score 0):

What comes to my mind is that you need to confirm that the color modes are exactly the same and that the PDF settings is not changing the color mode.

But this also depends on what type of objects you have, especially if you have transparency or different blending modes.

If you have them it is a good option to flatten them into a bitmap (but do it on a copy of the file)